# how to move to a specific node at neo4j-shell start

Tags: neo4j

When I start neo4j-shell, I am assigned in no nodes

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ ls
Not currently standing on any entity.
neo4j-sh (?)$ pwd
Current is (?)
(?)
```

Suppose I created a node like this:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE (n:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 1
19 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH n RETURN n LIMIT 25;           
+---------------------------+
| n                         |
+---------------------------+
| Node[4]{name:"Tom Hanks"} |
+---------------------------+
1 row
17 ms
```

Now how to move to the node I have just created without creating any new empty node?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the noob question. :)

But I may think this will help somebody.
We can move to just specific node by:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ cd 4
neo4j-sh (Tom Hanks,4)$
```

Comment: and `cd -a 4` if it is a disconnected node. See also `help cd`